# Character walks slow in my C# game

Tags: c#, performance, draw

The issue is **I can't figure out why my character moves slow when I draw an image**. All the timers are set to 1 interval and never changed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the entire project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rice_Boy_Tester_2
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    bool iggy = false;
    bool left2 = false;
    bool right2 = false;
    bool Up2 = false;
    bool Down2 = false;
    bool Check2 = false;

    bool left = false;
    bool right = false;
    bool Up = false;
    bool Down = false;
    bool Check = false;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Empty block
    }


    private void Refresh_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Refresh();

    }

    private void PriceBoyWalk_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (left) // Goes Left
            Player.Left -= 1;

        if (Player.Left < 170 & Check == false) {
            // Checks how far away player is from form
            left = false;
            Up = true;
        }
        if (Up & Player.Left < 170) { // Goes Up
            Player.Top -= 1;
            Check = true;
        }

        if (Player.Top < 100 & Check) {
            Up = false;
            Down = true;

        }

        if (right) // Goes Right
            Player.Left += 1;

        if (Down) // Goes Down
            Player.Top += 1;

        if (Player.Top + 150 > this.ClientSize.Height) {
            Check = false;
            Down = false;
            right = true;
        }


        if (Player.Left + 150 > this.ClientSize.Width)
            right = false;

    }
    private void B1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(form1_Pad1_Rice);
        RiceBoyWalkGif.Enabled = true;
        left = true;
        left2 = true;
        RiceBoyWalk.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (left2) {
            Player.Image = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Left-Bouncing.gif"); // Animates RiceBoyWalkingLeft
            left2 = false;

        }
        if (Player.Left < 170 & Check2 == false) {
            // Checks how far away the player is from form
            left2 = false;
            Up2 = true;

        }
        if (Up2 & Player.Left < 170) { // Goes Up
            this.Player.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(36, 76); // Changes size of the picture box to maintain quality 
            Player.Image = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Up-Bouncing.gif"); // Animates RiceBoyWalkingUp
            Check2 = true;
            Up2 = false;

        }

        if (Player.Top < 101 & Check2) {
            // Player.Top < 101 must be +1 greater than the RiceBoyWalkTimer
            Up2 = false;
            Down2 = true;

        }

        if (right2) {
            this.Player.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 77); // Changes size of the picture box to maintain quality 
            Player.Image = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Right-Bouncing.gif"); // Animates RiceBoyWalkingRight
            right2 = false;

        }

        if (Down2) { // Goes Down
            Player.Image = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Down.gif");
            Down2 = false;

        }

        if (Player.Top + 150 > this.ClientSize.Height) {
            iggy = true; // Shows that riceboy is approaching the starting point
            Check2 = false;
            Down2 = false;
            right2 = true;
        }

        if (Player.Left + 150 > this.ClientSize.Width & iggy) {
            right2 = false;
            Player.Image = Properties.Resources.Rice_Boy_Standing_Left;
        }

    }
    private void form1_Pad1_Rice(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Corn_Cobs, 120, 58, 50, 50);
        // Draws Corn cobs Character goes slower when corn is drawing
        // (x(-left), y(-Up), W, H) 
    }
```

Comment: @Unihedron the OP will get laughed at at GameDev for this. If a question has the word "game" in it, it does not mean that the question should be automatically redirected to GameDev. In my opinion this question fits better here than there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with this:

> Player.Image = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Down.gif");

(and the other load routines).

On every tick? Seriously?

Load them once during initialization, store them in variables, reuse the images. Ever played a computer game? They are not trashing your disc trying to load all graphics asset every frame.

Disc access is slow. Image decoding is slow. And I doubt you change the images while the program runs.

Comment: Thank you for your response Someone edited out i am kinda new to programming and that this code isn't very good But just how would i go about loading them and then storing them into variables.   Like Put Player.Image = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Down.gif"); and the others in the Form1_load  and then assign them to variables and use those variables in the timer so i can change the animation

Comment: @user3750839 - A simple way is to just create an array of images:  `Image[] gameImages = new Image[5];  gameImages[0] = Image.FromFile("Rice-Boy-Walking-Left-Bouncing.gif");`  Change the 5 to the correct number of images and load each image into successive indexes.

Comment: OK i have created an array of images but im not sure what you mean by successive indexes could you please provide an example and would this make my character faster? thank you for your time